# React - passing ref to sibling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to have 2 **sibling** components, and 1 of them has to have a reference to another - is that possible?

I tried this:

```
<button ref="btn">ok</button>
<PopupComponent triggerButton={this.refs.btn} />
```

And even this

```
<button ref="btn">ok</button>
<PopupComponent getTriggerButton={() => this.refs.btn} />
```

But I get `undefined` in both situations. Any ideas?

Note: a parent component will not work for me, because I need to have multiple sets of those, like

```
<button />
<PopupComponent />
<button />
<PopupComponent />
<button />
<PopupComponent />
```

NOT like this:

```
<div>
  <button />
  <PopupComponent />
</div>
<div>
  <button />
  <PopupComponent />
</div>
<div>
  <button />
  <PopupComponent />
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask why the second alternative is not a viable solution in your case? Because that's exactly how I'd solve this kind of problem.

Comment: well I guess it's mostly just css reasons... I'm using semantic-ui - the PopupComponent is actually either display:none; or position:absolute; and have a parent on those 2 really messes everything up...

Comment: So you're just using the ref to show / hide the `PopupComponent`?

Comment: yes. After some fiddling I'll use the parent after all I think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think this question is best answered by the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html):

> If you have not programmed several apps with React, your first
>   inclination is usually going to be to try to use refs to "make things
>   happen" in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more
>   critically about where state should be owned in the component
>   hierarchy. Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to "own" that
>   state is at a higher level in the hierarchy. Placing the state there
>   often eliminates any desire to use refs to "make things happen" –
>   instead, the data flow will usually accomplish your goal.

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but my hunch is a parent component and passing props is what you really want here.

Comment: I do need refs, because I'm using semantic-ui, and I need to grab 1 element with jQuery and is another element (popup trigger and popup target)

Comment: Mixing react and jQuery is a very bad idea, with a high risk of breaking react. For react to do its magic (very fast and efficient DOM updates), it needs a complete monopoly over the DOM parts it is managing.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with the quote Mark McKelvy has provided. What you are trying to achieve is considered an anti-pattern in React.

I'll add that creating a parent component doesn't necessarily means it has to be a direct parent, you can create a parent component further up the chain, in which you can render an array of all your children components together, having the logic to coordinate between all the children (or pairs of children according to your example) sit inside your parent.

I created a rough example of the concept which should do the trick:

```
class A extends React.Component {
    onClick(key) {
        alert(this.refs[key].refs.main.innerText);
    }

    render() {
        var children = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            children.push.apply(children, this.renderPair(i));

        return (
            <div>
                {children}
            </div>
        );
    }

    renderPair(key) {
        return [
            <B ref={'B' + key} key={'B' + key} onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'C' + key)}/>,
            <C ref={'C' + key} key={'C' + key} onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'B' + key)}/>
        ];
    }
}

class B extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p ref="main" onClick={this.props.onClick}>B</p>;
    }
}

class C extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p ref="main" onClick={this.props.onClick}>C</p>;
    }
}


React.render(<A/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

And any state you need to save for all your children, you do in the common parent. I really hope this helps.

Comment: is rendering an array really possible? I'm getting an error: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: EventPopup.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: Which version are you using? I did the same thing today.

Comment: React version 0.14.3

Comment: I'll be near a computer in 20 minutes, I'll make you a fiddle. Perhaps I got something wrong, but I have used a similar trick a couple of times now.

Comment: Wow, it's really hard to make a JSFiddle using React, sorry about that. I checked my previous code and indeed I was mistaken. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Just to explain my latest edit a bit further, in case there are some layers between the logical parent and its children, I usually created wrapper components that sits at the top layer, acts as the middle layers and its children will be the bottom layer. That way you can pass props through a deep tree without passing through all the middle layers, which will probably cause unnecessary coupling.

Answer (score 2):

The following code helps me to setup communication between two siblings. The setup is done in their parent during render() and componentDidMount() calls. Hope it helps.

```
class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
    private _navigationPanel: NavigationPanel;
    private _mapPanel: MapPanel;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
    }

    // `componentDidMount()` is called by ReactJS after `render()`
    componentDidMount() {
        // Pass _mapPanel to _navigationPanel
        // It will allow _navigationPanel to call _mapPanel directly
        this._navigationPanel.setMapPanel(this._mapPanel);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="appDiv" style={divStyle}>
                // `ref=` helps to get reference to a child during rendering
                <NavigationPanel ref={(child) => { this._navigationPanel = child; }} />
                <MapPanel ref={(child) => { this._mapPanel = child; }} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[special-props](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/special-props.html)

Special Props Warning
Most props on a JSX element are passed on to the component, however, there are two special props (ref and key) which are used by React, and are thus not forwarded to the component.

For instance, attempting to access this.props.key from a component (eg. the render function) is not defined. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop (ex: ). While this may seem redundant, it's important to separate app logic from reconciling hints.